# Error: No "sanity.json" file found in plugin "@sanity/base"

Tags: sanity

I am new to sanity and trying to follow along to a tutorial on youtube but I am getting this error when I run ' sanity start'. Can anyone give me advice on what I should do?

[sanity error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7UnF.png)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, running `sanity install` solved this issue.

If it won't help, try manually deleting **node_modules** folder and *then* run `sanity install`.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Find the "@sanity/base" in sanity.json
2/ Remove it all "env" in below

```
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "@sanity/base"
      ]
    }
  },
```

3/ Start again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`sanity upgrade` will solve the issue